# Math formula for perfectly fitting buttons in current devices screen width

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, sprite-kit

Could someone point me in the right direction for figuring out how to properly write out my code so that all buttons on any particular y-axis would try to fit the width of the current device screen as best as possible?

To be more exact, currently, I have 4 buttons (made from a SKSpriteNode) that need to be positioned within the screen in such a way that they look perfectly fitted. Device screen is portrait, although from a math point of view, that wouldn't matter, only the actual width of the screen. Each button width uses the same texture, thus resulting in identical widths, but the texture it self might change from time to time resulting in each buttons width either to shrink a little or expand.

Right now, my positioning code looks as follows:

```
btnLvl1.position = CGPointMake(_scrollingNode.size.width/20*3, scrollStart.position.y - 60);
btnLvl2.position = CGPointMake(_scrollingNode.size.width/20*8, scrollStart.position.y - 60);
btnLvl3.position = CGPointMake(_scrollingNode.size.width/20*13, scrollStart.position.y - 60);
btnLvl4.position = CGPointMake(_scrollingNode.size.width/20*18, scrollStart.position.y - 60);
```

I was hoping someone could recommend a math formula for making sure, regardless of each button width & how many buttons there are, that they would be placed within the screen width as best as possible. A super bonus would be if something could be done for the height of a device screen (but not necessary).

P.S. I did try figuring this one out my self, but I'm not very strong math-wise.

Comment: Use your scene size proportions then making your button.size and button.possition

Comment: How would I do that in code? Could you type an example please?

Comment: Why don't you use autolayout? It does the math for you.

Comment: I'm doing all of this inside SpriteKit's SKScene (since it's a game) & I've never seen anyone use auto layout for it. I don't even know how to set it up for an SKScene...

Comment: What is the result currently?  Is it that the nodes are slightly too wide for the screen?  In your view controller, what do you define for the fill (Aspect Fill, Fill)?  Also in your view controller, do you define the size of the Sprite Kit scene (default is 1024x768)?

Comment: The SKSpriteNode buttons are currently at a size at which they look visually pleasing. When the scene is created inside a UIViewController, it looks like this: 

//Create & configure the scene.
        SKScene *sceneGame  = [MainMenuScene sceneWithSize:_skView.bounds.size];
        sceneGame.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
        
        //Present the scene.
        [_skView presentScene:sceneGame transition:[SKTransition fadeWithDuration:0.5]];

Answer (score 0):

You can use your scene size to "auto-fit" any node. For example, if you want to center a button on the screen:

```
button.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
```

Although you can use this:

```
button.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
```